# Sitecore TDS Packages vs Sitecore packages

Tags: package, sitecore, tds

I am new to Sitecore and TDS.  Are the packages created by TDS the same as the packages created by Sitecore Package Designer?  If not what is the difference.  Plus how do I create a package using TDS.  From what I saw TDS creates "Update Packages" although I am not sure what this means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sitecore package and TDS Packages are different. With TDS, you make make use of the Sitecore Package Deployer to automatically install the package.

As you have seen, TDS creates .update package. These package can only be installed via the Sitecore updateInstallationWizard page. It is an ASPX page found in the admin folder within the website folder.

The sitecore package on the other hand, is installed using the cms. That is you need to go to the sitecore menu and click on the installation wizard. Its extension is .zip

You can check the following documentation here [link](http://www.hhogdev.com/~/media/Files/Products/Team_Development/Getting%20started%20with%20Team%20Development%20for%20Sitecore.pdf) for more information how to generate package from TDS.

Comment: What is the purpose of the updateInstallationWizard.aspx page?  Is this something especially created to support TDS?  If not then what is the purpose of having two formats.

Plus what is the standard way in which you deploy updated SiteCore packages created through the PackageDesigner?

Comment: The updateinstallationwizard.aspx is an in-built page when installing the Sitecore Instance. Normally, most upgrade package from Sitecore is done using the .update package. For example, upgrading sitecore version 7.5 to 8. Since this page is already available, it is TDS who decided to make use of this page. The common scenario is when you create package from one environment and needs to install it to another environment you will be using the PackageDesigner but when taking item from local instance to a Staging environment, you can use the TDS to perform it

Comment: So if I am updating a solution already deployed at a client site I should use the Install Package wizard?  Why would I want to use updateinstallationwizard when taking an item from staging from production?  Shouldn't the package created by package designer handle this?

Comment: When upgrading your sitecore version, it is done via the .update package. So you will be using the updateinstallationwizard. When deploying items from one environment to another you make use of the package designer and use the installation window